Spotify player authentication
There's a code snippet
import React, { useState,useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import SpotifyWebApi from 'spotify-web-api-js';

const spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi();

const MusicPlayer = () => {
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    const accessToken = "I have to place my token here i guess";
    spotifyApi.setAccessToken(accessToken);
  },[])
  const playMusic = async () => {
    try {

      const trackName = 'Mesélek a bornak';

      const searchResult = await spotifyApi.searchTracks(trackName);

      const trackUri = searchResult.tracks.items[0].uri;

      await spotifyApi.play({ uris: [trackUri] });
      setIsPlaying(true);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Hiba történt a zene lejátszása közben:', error);
    }
  };

  const stopMusic = () => {
    spotifyApi.pause();
    setIsPlaying(false);
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{isPlaying ? 'Music has been played' : 'There is no active playing'}</Text>
      <Button title={isPlaying ? 'Stop' : 'Start'} onPress={isPlaying ? stopMusic : playMusic} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default MusicPlayer;


So, the app can find the music (as you can see the trackName is "Mesélek a bornak") BUT, when i try to use the spotifyApi.play method, it retrurns 401 permission denied error code.
I guess it's beacuse I didn't provide the bearer token. But how can i earn it from spotify? I guess I have to do that programatically, beacuse token always changes.
Can someone help with an example code?
App has already registered in spotify dev console and already have client_id and client_secret as well.
Thank you for replies!
